# Java Client/Server tcp messages incorrect

Tags: java

I'm writing a Client/Server application where the client sends a server a username and the server responds with a challenge however I'm having issues with the client receiving the challenge. It seems as though the challenge is just getting dropped or replaced with another array of bytes (which happens to be exactly the same each time). Any suggestions for this would be much appreciated.

Client Code:

```
public class ClientOrig {
  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    // Complain if we don't get the right number of arguments. 
    if ( args.length != 1 ) {
      System.out.println( "Usage: Client <host>" );
      System.exit( -1 );
    }

    try {
      // Try to create a socket connection to the server.
      Socket sock = new Socket( args[ 0 ], ServerOriginal.PORT_NUMBER );

      // Get formatted input/output streams for talking with the server.
      DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream( sock.getInputStream() );
      DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream( sock.getOutputStream() );

      // Get a username from the user and send it to the server.
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );
      System.out.print( "Username: " );
            String name = scanner.nextLine();
      output.writeUTF( name );
      output.flush();

      byte[] challenge = ServerOriginal.getMessage( input );
      System.out.println(challenge);
      String request = "";
      System.out.print( "cmd> " );

      // We are done communicating with the server.
      sock.close();
    } catch( IOException e ){
      System.err.println( "IO Error: " + e );
    }
  }
}
```

Server Code:

```
  public static byte[] getMessage( DataInputStream input ) throws IOException {
    int len = input.readInt();
    byte[] msg = new byte [ len ];
    input.readFully( msg );
    System.out.println("Read: " + msg + " which is " + msg.length);
    System.out.println("Byte to string: " + new String(msg));
    return msg;
  }

  /** Function analogous to the previous one, for sending messages. */
  public static void putMessage( DataOutputStream output, byte[] msg ) throws IOException {
    output.writeInt(msg.length);
    output.write( msg, 0, msg.length );
    System.out.println("Writing: "+ msg + " which is " + msg.length);
    output.flush();

  }

  /** Function to handle interaction with a client.  Really, this should
      be run in a thread. */
  public void handleClient( Socket sock ) {
    try {
      // Get formatted input/output streams for this thread.  These can read and write
      // strings, arrays of bytes, ints, lots of things.
      DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream( sock.getOutputStream() );
      DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream( sock.getInputStream() );

      // Get the username.
      String username = input.readUTF();
      System.out.println(username);
      // Make a random sequence of bytes to use as a challenge string.
      Random rand = new Random();
      byte[] challenge = new byte [ 16 ];
      System.out.println(challenge);
      rand.nextBytes( challenge );
      System.out.println(challenge);
      putMessage(output, challenge);
        // Send the client the challenge.
      putMessage( output, challenge );
      getMessage(input);

    } catch ( IOException e ) {
      System.out.println( "IO Error: " + e );
    } finally {
      try {
        // Close the socket on the way out.
        sock.close();
      } catch ( Exception e ) {
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: perfect time to debug your code

Comment: Why do you believe that your code is not working? Could you please clarify

Comment: Sure. I print out the array of bytes on the server before I send it and then print out the array of bytes on the client when I receive the bytes and they're completely different.  It seems like something is happening on the networking side. The odd thing is that the client prints out the same array of bytes every time.